# Cutting up the x-axis to produce multiple graphs with seaborn?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

The following code when graphed looks really messy at the moment. The reason is I have too many values for 'fare'. 'Fare' ranges from [0-500] with most of the values within the first 100.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")



y =titanic.groupby([titanic.fare//1,'sex']).survived.mean().reset_index()




sns.set(style="whitegrid")
g = sns.factorplot(x='fare', y= 'survived', col = 'sex', kind ='bar' ,data= y,
               size=4, aspect =2.5 , palette="muted")
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_ylabels("Survival Probability")
g.set_xlabels('Fare')
plt.show()
```

I would like to try slicing up the 'fare' of the plots into subsets but would like to see all the graphs at the same time on one screen. I was wondering it this is possible without having to resort to groupby. 
I will have to play around with the values of 'fare' to see what I would want each graph to represent, but for a sample let's use break up the graph into these 'fare' values.

```
[0-18]
[18-35]
[35-70]
[70-300]
[300-500]
```

So the total would be 10 graphs on one page, because of the juxtaposition with the opposite sex.

Is it possible with Seaborn? Do I need to do a lot of configuring with matplotlib? Thanks.

Comment: Use `pd.cut` to define categorical fare bins and use it as one of the faceting variables in `factorplot.

Comment: Thanks I'm playing around with it right now.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I wrote a little [blog post about this a while ago](http://themrmax.github.io/2015/11/13/grouped-histograms-for-categorical-data-in-pandas.html). If you are plotting histograms you can use the `by` keyword:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.apionly as sns

sns.set() #rescue matplotlib's styles from the early '90s

data = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
data.hist(by='class', column = 'fare')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Otherwise if you're just plotting value-counts, you have to roll your own grid:

```
def categorical_hist(self,column,by,layout=None,legend=None,**params):
  from math import sqrt, ceil
  if layout==None:
    s = ceil(sqrt(self[column].unique().size))
    layout = (s,s)

  return self.groupby(by)[column]\
             .value_counts()\
             .sort_index()\
             .unstack()\
             .plot.bar(subplots=True,layout=layout,legend=None,**params)


categorical_hist(data, by='class', column='embark_town')
```

[image]

**Edit**  If you want survival rate by fare range, you could do something like  this

```
data.groupby(pd.cut(data.fare,10)).apply(lambda x.survived.sum(): x./len(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how would I get "survivability" on the left side(y-axis)? Is there a way to control the x-axis ticks, so I can input the numbers I want the graph to be divided by? Nice blog by the way. I learned about "unstack"  =)

Comment: @moondra for a histogram you can control the x-axis with the `bins`, see my edit for survial rates by fare range

Comment: BTW, how did you post an image of your graph here? Did you have to save the image first and then upload to a site, and use that link?

Comment: @moondra Actually you can use copy paste when you're in the "upload image" dialogue box

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was that simple.